# Can Envoy encrypts raw TCP connection?

Tags: envoyproxy

We want to encrpyt raw TCP data traffic. For example, some data is trasferred using iSCSI (over TCP) which is not encrypted.

Can we use Envoy as a middle proxy to encrypt the data when the data is going through the network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt data between your client and Envoy by using [`TcpProxy`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/filters/network/tcp_proxy/v3/tcp_proxy.proto) with a [`DownstreamTlsContext`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.21.0/api-v3/extensions/transport_sockets/tls/v3/tls.proto.html) defined in the `transport_socket` section.

Assuming you have the root CA certificate (`/certs/rootCA.crt`), your server certificate (`/certs/server.crt`) and your private key as a PEM file (`cat server.crt server.key > /certs/server.pem`), the envoy config will look like this :

```yaml
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 1111
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.tcp_proxy
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
          stat_prefix: tcp_proxy
          cluster: my_service
      transport_socket:
        name: tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain:
                filename: "/certs/server.crt"
              private_key:
                filename: "/certs/server.pem"
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca:
                filename: "/certs/rootCA.crt"
              allow_expired_certificate: false
          require_client_certificate: false

  clusters:
  - name: my_service
    connect_timeout: 15s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: my_service
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: my_service
                port_value: 2222
```

You can easily check that the traffic between the client and envoy is encrypted by using a tool like wireshark or tcpdump.